# Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap.min.css' in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

*./src/style.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/style.css) Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap.min.css' in 'C:\react\adama\src'*

I keep getting this error in my React project.

*package.json*

```
  "name": "adama",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
```

*App.js*

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './style.css'
import './responsive.css'
```

I have a bootstrap folder in my node_modules directory. I've tried various suggested fixes and nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your webpack setup. Can you share your webpack config? Did you create the app using create-react-app? See [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/webpack).

Comment: I created the app using create-react-app

Comment: I think the problem is with the import statement in style.css.
`@import "bootstrap.min.css"`
Can this kind of import work in react and if not, what's the alternative?

Comment: Good point that the error is showing the issue in `styles.css`. 1) Why are you importing bootstrap in both App.js and style.css? You only need to import it once ([CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/) suggest importing in `.js`). 2) You can try `@import "~bootstrap.min.css"`. The `~` will tell it to look in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your *App.js* Wouldnt it be:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './style.css'
import './responsive.css'
```